# Dynamicly set HTTP_PROXY in an ansible playbook

Tags: proxy, ansible, http-proxy

I'm running a playbook either on a bunch of servers with no need of http_proxy and others with needs of it (on different runs).

I've read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html but it doesn't really answer this...

here's an example:

`- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: install vi
      become: true
      apt:
        name: vi
      state: present`

I would like to launch it with a group of servers (let's say server01-atlanta) without proxy and in another run with a group of servers (let's say server01-berlin) with proxy and without changing the code between each run (so managing to do it with inventory variables).

I would

Comment: Could you please provide an example. Who and when does need a http_proxy and for what? Would be great if you were a little bit more precise in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this with **group_vars** / **host_vars** in combination with environment variables. Her is a simple example based on the code from ansible docs.

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    proxy: # default empty
  tasks:    
    - apt: name=cobbler state=installed
      environment:
        http_proxy: "{{ proxy }}"
```

This is how you define a environment variable per task. You can also use normal ansible variables for this. There is also a example with proxy settings and variables in the docs. See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

In your inventory you can define the proxy variable per host or group:

```
atlanta:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
  vars:
    proxy: proxy.atlanta.example.com
```

See inventory docs for more details: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#host-variables

Comment: Hello, I will test your solution. Thanks !

Comment: Your're welcome. Give me a upvote if it's the solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering you can also set this via the command line with the following:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "http_proxy=$http_proxy" ...
```

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140789/how-to-inject-local-shell-variables-into-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

flxPeters answer is kind-of sound, however it has a small flaw: Ansible's variable precedence rules are preventing his implementation to work as intended.

As noted [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable):

> **Understanding variable precedence**
>
> Ansible does apply variable precedence, and you might have a use for
> it. Here is the order of precedence **from least to greatest** (the last
> listed variables override all other variables):
>
> 1. command line values (for example, -u my_user, these are not variables)
> 2. role defaults (defined in role/defaults/main.yml)
> 3. inventory file or script group vars
> 4. inventory group_vars/all
> 5. playbook group_vars/all
> 6. **inventory group_vars/**
> 7. playbook group_vars/
> 8. inventory file or script host vars
> 9. inventory host_vars/
> 10. playbook host_vars/
> 11. host facts / cached set_facts
> 12. **play vars**
> 13. play vars_prompt
> 14. play vars_files
> 15. role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)
> 16. block vars (only for tasks in block)
> 17. task vars (only for the task)
> 18. include_vars
> 19. set_facts / registered vars
> 20. role (and include_role) params
> 21. include params
> 22. extra vars (for example, -e "user=my_user")(always win precedence)

So, since `play_vars` (12) have higher precedence than `inventory group_vars` (6), the value we get for `https_proxy:` will always be an empty string - That is, (12) overrides (6):

```
TASK [show "proxy" fact value for this host] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01.mylab.lan] => {
    "proxy": null
}
```

An elegant solution for this would be to define a default value for the `proxy` fact on a `common` role `defaults/main.yml` file, like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p roles/common/defaults
touch main.yml
cat << EOF > roles/common/defaults/main.yml
my_proxy: # empty by default
EOF
```

Then, we need to include the role on our playbook -there are several ways to do that, but we want our default var value to have a playbook scope, so we include it at a play level:

```
---
- name: My Test Play
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - common
  tasks:    
    - apt: name=cobbler state=installed
      environment:
        http_proxy: "{{ my_proxy }}"
```

Cheers