# How to inject local shell variables into ansible

Tags: ansible

Here's my intention:

I have a VM linux in the Virtualbox with a bridge network, say it's ip is `192.168.1.11`, and i run a http proxy on the hosted mac, say it's `192.168.1.4:1087`, because the ip of the host mac, `192.168.1.4` is a dhcp address and may changed.

I created a `update_http_proxy.sh` on mac and run it towards the VM with ansible.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/profile | egrep -v 'http_proxy|https_proxy|no_proxy' > /tmp/profile_$$

cat >> /tmp/profile_$$ <<EOF

export http_proxy={{ http_proxy }} # this is not replaced with the mac variables
export https_proxy=http://192.168.1.4:1087 # this works but I have to edit the shell when the mac ip changed.
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,localhost,192.0.0.0/8"
EOF
cp /tmp/profile_$$ /etc/profile
```

This file will be uploaded to the VM and executed. but how to replace the `{{ http_proxy }} with the env varialbe $http_proxy on the mac before uploaded to the remote VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This file will be uploaded to the VM and executed. but how to replace the `{{ http_proxy }} with the env varialbe $http_proxy on the mac before uploaded to the remote VM?

The thing you are looking for is `--extra-vars`, or to add such information to a dynamic inventory script

```
$ ansible-playbook --extra-vars "http_proxy=$http_proxy" ...
```

You can also delegate to your localhost to grab its ip address, to avoid having to do any kind of launch specialness:

```
- name: get the control host info
  setup:
  delegate_to: localhost
- name: get the control host info
  set_fact:
    host_ip: '{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}'
- name: re-gather facts of target host
  setup:
- set_fact:
    http_proxy: http://{{ host_ip }}:1087
```

You can optionally run the playbook with `gather_facts: no` to avoid having to do the initial fact gathering, since you'll have to re-gather the facts due to a quirk of `setup:` always overwriting `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` and not `hostvars["localhost"]` as one might *expect* that `delegate_to:` to do